# What "humane client library" r2dbc-postresql implementations exist?

Tags: java, postgresql, reactive, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I've come from Scala background using Akka streams and Slick to access DB.

I'd like to introduce reactive programming to my current workplace, which is a Java shop.  I've been looking at how to access PostgreSQL using reactive stack, and looks like `r2dbc-postgresql` is the way to go.  However, [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql) mentions that the library isn't intended to be used directly:

> This implementation is not intended to be used directly, but rather to be used as the backing implementation for a humane client library to delegate to.

So far, I've that [Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc) is an implementation of the `r2dbc-postgresql`. However, I'd like to avoid Spring, if at all possible.

Are there any other alternatives to Spring Data or `r2dbc`?

Comment: If you want to use r2dbc then use r2dbc. Nothing humane about it. [SomeEntityDao.java](https://github.com/karlnicholas/WebFluxR2dbc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/webfluxplay/dao/SomeEntityDao.java).

Comment: I think this is a great question, but unfortunately one that is off topic for Stack Overflow [due to being a library recommendation question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: There's a little extra context in [this issue](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-spi/issues/162#issuecomment-598908146) on why it's recommended not to be used directly: "Using R2DBC SPI directly is possible, yet not very convenient when trying to use it from your regular application. That is why we recommend the usage of an R2DBC client library."